# Were there any other "Mythos Transfers", other than the Greek-Roman transfer?

Tags: comparative

Were there any other Mythos Transfers, other than the Greek-Roman transfer?

To clarify, I mean an almost complete copy of another religion/myth system.

The greek-roman mythos transfer was basically an adaption of ideas from greek to roman.

Comment: None of them were ever all-encompassing. When separated peoples came into contact, there was always a blend, and that includes the Greeks and Romans.

Comment: Sumerian to Babylonian?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ideas (not just "myths" or "mythos") spread from one culture to another all of the time. When two cultures come into contact with each other (or even when two people come into contact with each other), they inevitably share ideas with each other. I would give examples, but this happens so frequently, so I'm not quite sure what doing so would accomplish.

I suppose that by "mythos transfers" you mean one culture adopting another cultures "mythology" (more accurately religion). The answer is again yes, although you should get more specific about what you mean by "mythos transfers." "Mythos transfers" occur throughout history for a variety of reasons. I suppose one example of a "mythos transfer" would be European conquistadors converting those they conquer to Christianity. Another example would be Buddhism spreading from India to China. Again, this occurs for many different reasons, so you really should be more specific about what you mean by "mythos transfer."

(You should know that "mythos transfer" is a completely nonsensical and made up phrase. Also, in this case you are talking less about mythology and more about religion.)

Comment: I mean, well, a complete adaption of ideas, not converting, and myth systems specifically.

Comment: @bleh `"a complete adaption of ideas"` the romans, which was the example you gave in your question, made many changes to the Greek religion. `"myth systems specifically"` Myth doesn't make sense in this context. Religion is a better word. Besides, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "myth systems" `:not converting"` Not quite sure what you mean by converting. I'm pretty sure that the spread of Buddhism to China was mostly nonviolent, although I could be wrong.